# Create table across all schemas at once

Tags: database, oracle, schema

Is it possible to create a table across every schema in your database?
Specifically in Oracle.

I do not want to run the exact same query for all existing schemas.

Solution i have been using is,

Use below query to get all schema names,

```
select distinct owner FROM all_tables;
```

Get the result and use regular expression to append/prepend your table creation query.

```
^ - create table
$ - .tablename \( column1 varchar2(10)\);
```

run all the resulting queries in oracle work sheet.

Comment: Short answer   .. no

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Slightly longer answer: No, because Oracle didn't feel it was necessary to develop tools for such an odd (and probably very rare) requirement. It is hard to imagine why one would have to create the exact same table for all existing schemas (and by the way I hope you don't want to include SYS in your "all" ... )

Comment: I agree with @mathguy. I can remember doing stuff like this twenty years ago but Oracle has added lots of features since then. I can't remember the last time I needed to build a *table* in every schema. You should explain why you think you need to do this, what's the rationale? Probably there's a better way to achieve the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of *PL/SQL* and *execute immediate* to do this.
For example you can create a table in all schemas if you connect as SYS User and execute the following Script:

```
begin
    for cUsers in (select * from dba_users where account_status ='OPEN')
    loop
        execute immediate 'create table '||cUsers.username||'.myTable ( id number )';
    end loop;
end;
```